# How can I transcode flac to ogg-flac?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

How can I transcode flac to [ogg-flac](https://xiph.org/flac/ogg_mapping.html) ? It seems that ffmpeg supports only flac, not ogg-flac.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `-f ogg` somewhere between `-i the_input_file` and `the_output_file.flac` or simply use `the_output_file.ogg`. (I have no idea whether using .flac is considered legal for Ogg FLAC.)

Because the output container format determines the default codec to use for the output streams (IIRC), make sure your add `-c:a flac` (similarly, somewhere between between `-i the_input_file` and `the_output_file`) to specify your desired audio codec, as the default one for ogg is vorbis.

<s>`-f flac` is implied for the flac encoder when no muxer is specified (and when there is only an audio input).</s>

Comment: `-f flac` is implied for output URLs ending in `.flac`. ffmpeg does not take the choice of encoder as hint for container.

Comment: ah right. so having `.ogg` would have work and `-f ogg` is only needed if you insists `.flac`.

Comment: This does not work: `ffmpeg.exe -i .\103_1.flac -f ogg  103_1.flog` with leads to `Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))` which is not ogg-flac but ogg vorbis.

Comment: @Soleil answer updated